# Creating Dashboard in SharePoint Online

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, content-type, dashboard

Is there anything OOB in SharePoint Online (2013) that would allow me to pull information from a Site Content Type.

I built 5 custom lists on a site and all are using the same site content type.
I did this in hopes that I can pull information and a create report of some type for auditing purposes.

Comment: Did you try Content Query web part?

Comment: I was just reading about that. I have just started looking at how to do this, and trying to figure out where to start. I don't really have that much development experience. Is it fairly easy to use?

Comment: Yes. It is easy and can be achieved in few steps.

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, you can try Content Query WebPart. And we can also use Content Search Web Part depending on the requirement.

You can the article to know the [differences between the Content Query and Content Search Web Parts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/When-to-use-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-or-the-Content-Search-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-346a0f48-38de-409b-8a58-3bdca1768929?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) before your start implementing.

If you are new to Content Query web part watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmhq4Ed_WjY) to get started.

Comment: I looked at the Content Search Web Part, and I'm not exactly sure if its what I'm looking for. What I'm wanting is a tool that the user can use. For example: Enter in an Invoice Number and have it pull any information that it relates to. Is this possible?

Comment: This can be achieved using coding using search functionality if you want results from the multiple lists. The results from single list can be achieved using HTML Form Web Part. Let me know where your scenario sits. I will give some insight on approach.

Comment: I have multiple lists that need to be searched, and they will be large lists.

Comment: The best approach would be building a custom feature using REST API. The steps would be `1. Add a text box, button and table to the Content Editor Web Part.`. `2. Add a JavaScript function which makes a call to Search REST Api with filters`. `3. Bind search results to a HTML table`. I can answer any doubt you have.